# How to know when the Swing JTree has rendered all changes?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

So I've modified my tree structure and asked my tree model to reload it. How to know when the JTree component has finished rendering the changes?

Answer (score 2):

This is partially covered within the following Oracle documents:

- [How to use trees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic)
- [How to Write a Tree Model Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treemodellistener.html)
- [`TreeModelListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeModelListener.html#treeStructureChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent)) and implementing classes

---

By adding your own listener, you can monitor changes. However, the `DefaultTreeModel` processes the listeners from last to first when notifying changes (Source: [DefaultTreeModel](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.java)):

```
// Process the listeners last to first, notifying those that are interested in this event
```

Therefore, in order to ensure your listener will be notified *after* the changes have been rendered / completed, you need your listener to be executed after those already being used internally within `JTree` to handle changes. By extending the `DefaultTreeModel` and overriding these methods you can change the order the listeners are processed by modifying the for loop / introducing sorting

The `DynamicTreeDemo` and `DynamicTree` in the tutorial linked above provide a great basis to test this yourself as they provide methods of editing, inserting and deleting tree nodes, as well as completely modifying the tree structure (the clear option) via the UI. Each of which correspond to a method in the `TreeModelListener` that must be implemented

---

Here are examples you can test with by including

```
treeModel = new CustomTreeModel(rootNode);
treeModel.addTreeModelListener(new CustomTreeModelListener());
```

in the `DynamicTree` constructor

You can also add additional `TreeModelListener`'s to ensure they execute in the expected order

Model:

```
class CustomTreeModel extends DefaultTreeModel{
        public CustomTreeModel(TreeNode root){
            super(root);
        }

        @Override
        protected void fireTreeNodesChanged(Object source, Object[] path,
                                            int[] childIndices, Object[] children) {

            Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
            TreeModelEvent event = null;
            // Process the listeners first to last, notifying those that are interested in this event
            for (int index = 0; index < listeners.length; index++) {
                if (listeners[index] instanceof TreeModelListener) {
                    // Lazily create the event:
                    if (event == null)
                        event = new TreeModelEvent(source, path, childIndices, children);
                    ((TreeModelListener)listeners[index]).treeNodesChanged(event);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void fireTreeNodesInserted(Object source, Object[] path,
                                             int[] childIndices, Object[] children) {

            Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
            TreeModelEvent event = null;
            // Process the listeners first to last, notifying those that are interested in this event
            for (int index = 0; index < listeners.length; index++) {
                if (listeners[index] instanceof TreeModelListener) {
                    // Lazily create the event:
                    if (event == null)
                        event = new TreeModelEvent(source, path, childIndices, children);
                    ((TreeModelListener)listeners[index]).treeNodesInserted(event);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void fireTreeNodesRemoved(Object source, Object[] path,
                                            int[] childIndices, Object[] children) {

            Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
            TreeModelEvent event = null;
            // Process the listeners first to last, notifying those that are interested in this event
            for (int index = 0; index < listeners.length; index++) {
                if (listeners[index] instanceof TreeModelListener) {
                    // Lazily create the event:
                    if (event == null)
                        event = new TreeModelEvent(source, path, childIndices, children);
                    ((TreeModelListener)listeners[index]).treeNodesRemoved(event);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void fireTreeStructureChanged(Object source, Object[] path,
                                                int[] childIndices, Object[] children) {

            Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
            TreeModelEvent event = null;
            // Process the listeners first to last, notifying those that are interested in this event
            for (int index = 0; index < listeners.length; index++) {
                if (listeners[index] instanceof TreeModelListener) {
                    // Lazily create the event:
                    if (event == null)
                        event = new TreeModelEvent(source, path, childIndices, children);
                    ((TreeModelListener)listeners[index]).treeStructureChanged(event);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Listener:

```
class CustomTreeModelListener implements TreeModelListener {
    public void treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent();
        int index = e.getChildIndices()[0];
        DefaultMutableTreeNode modifiedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)(parentNode.getChildAt(index));

        System.out.println("A node on parent: " + parentNode.getUserObject()
                + " was modified to: " + modifiedNode.getUserObject());
    }

    public void treeNodesInserted(TreeModelEvent e) {
        String parentNode = e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent().toString();
        String childNodes = Arrays.toString(e.getChildren());
        System.out.println("Node(s): " + childNodes + " inserted to parent: " + parentNode);
    }

    public void treeNodesRemoved(TreeModelEvent e) {
        String parentNode = e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent().toString();
        String childNodes = Arrays.toString(e.getChildren());
        System.out.println("Node(s): " + childNodes + " removed from parent: " + parentNode);
    }

    public void treeStructureChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Tree structure has been updated");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain these callbacks will happen *after* the rendering is done, as the question asked? I was under the impression they would be called before, or concurrently. And I can't find anything from skimming your links that addresses this issue.

Comment: @DanGetz I've updated my answer, any feedback is welcome